# HTML Table with mixed fixed-width and fluid columns

Tags: html, html-table, fluid-layout, fixed-width

I have a table styled with `table-layout:fixed`. There are six columns in the table and I am setting the width of each column separately. For some columns, the text within is truncated. Is there any to way to set the width of particular column (one or two columns) based on the content?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [column group](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.4) and set the width of the specified column to the minimum required value determined by the content using the following syntax:

```
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col width="30"><!--fixed width column-->
    <col width="0*"><!--minimum width of content column-->
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <!--...-->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I want to set the width of one column based on the content and for other columns hard coded width.

Comment: In the aforementioned code, `"30"` would be the hardcoded width, `"0*"` would be the content-based width.